# Android - Still having problems setting tab when opening after closing with back button

Tags: android, android-tabhost, sharedpreferences

So I'm simply trying to 'remember' the tab that was selected when the app is closed using the back button.

Following an early question and some research I in my tabs I have:

```
    mSetTab();
}
public void onResume()
{
         super.onResume();
         mSetTab();
}
    private void mSetTab() 
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs =
        this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    myPrefs.edit().putInt("tabToggle", 2).commit();
}
```

Now I've tested this with another function that 'toasts' the value in "tabToggle" and it appears to be working quite happily.

In my MainActivity in OnCreate I have:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(mCheckTab());    
}
private int mCheckTab() 
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    int whichTab = myPrefs.getInt("tabToggle",0); 
    return whichTab;
}
```

This is frustrating me because it seems to always be returning 0 no matter what I do. So I think I've got part of the code wrong but can't work out what.

Any help as always is much appreciated.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Try using getApplicationContext() instead of this at this.getSharedPreferences.

Comment: Tried that didn't work:

I have:

private int mCheckTab() 
 {
  SharedPreferences myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
  int whichTab = myPrefs.getInt("tabToggle",0);
  Toast.makeText(this, "whichTab="+whichTab, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return whichTab;
 }

The toast returns 0 even though I know it should be 2.

However judging by the toasts being sent to screen. The first tab '0' is opened no matter what it's knows tabToggle is set to 2, but then sets it to 0 and I think it's doing this before I use tabHost.setCurrentTab().

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the mSetTab method from onResume(). You should be calling it from onPause().